# Create array in js that contains php

Tags: javascript, php

I want to create an array in js that conteins items, each item is a row form the DB, each item have id and name property.

i create this function in php:

```
function getECatTest(){
    $accountid = getAccountid($_SESSION[get("session_name")]);
    $aaa = array();

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `ExpensesCategorys`");   
    while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        //$cars[$result["category_id"]] = $result["category_name"];
        $cars = array($result["category_id"],$result["category_name"]);
        array_push($aaa,$cars);
        $count += 1;
    } 
    $js_array = json_encode($aaa);
    echo "window.test = ".$js_array.";\n";
}
```

and here is the js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        <?php getECatTest(); ?>

    </script>
```

now this is what i get:

```
        window.test = [["1","E1"],["2","E2"],["3","E3"],["4","E4"],["5","E5"],["6","E6"],["7","E7"],["8","E8"]];
```

i want to get it sorted like "id": "1", "name": "E1" and so on...
and i dont know how to accsses the code :D 
i mean if i want the id 1 only how i can get it?

i tryed this: window.test[1] but its return the id and the name...what if i want only the name? or only the id?

please help, and write how i can accses the code its important..

TY =]

Comment: `window.test[0][1]` to get the value: `E1`

Comment: If you want named properties, use an associative array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get named properties, use an associative array:

```
$cars = array('id' => $result['category_id'], 
              'name' => $result['category_name']);
$aaa[] = $cars;
```

Then the Javascript result will look like:

```
window.test = [ { "id": "1", "name": "E1" }, { "id": "2", "name": "E2" }, ...];
```

Then to access the first name, you use `window.test[0].name`.

Answer (score 0):

`window.test` is a two-dimensional array. You may use:

```
window.test[0][0] for 0'th element's id 
window.test[0][1] for 0'th element's value
```

or alternatively:

```
function getECatTest(){
    $accountid = getAccountid($_SESSION[get("session_name")]);
    $aaa = array();

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `ExpensesCategorys`");   
    while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        //$cars[$result["category_id"]] = $result["category_name"];
        $cars = array('id'=>$result["category_id"],'name'=>$result["category_name"]);
        array_push($aaa,$cars);
        $count += 1;
    } 
    $js_array = json_encode($aaa);
    echo "window.test = ".$js_array.";\n";
```

}

In javascript use:

```
for(element in window.test){
    alert(element.id + " " + element.name);
}
```